# How do I upgrade Ubuntu without it removing ia32-libs?

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

While trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 the updater looks like it's removing `ia32-libs` (okay, fine, I don't care) and *third party apps* that list it as a dependency. That is **not** okay.

How do I make it not remove my apps?

---

Note: the reason I'm extremely reluctant to allow this is that I have reason to not trust that reinstalling it after the fact will work correctly, if at all. (Among other things, I can't find anywhere that I can install the exact current version from!)

Comment: A question just like your's was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285370/can-i-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04-without-losing-my-data).

Comment: @Noonamous I don't see much if any connection between that question and mine. It is taking about the general problem where the answer is "do an an in-place upgrade", where as I'm asking about how to make the in-place upgrade I'm doing not uninstall something I need.  ---  As it happens, I was lucky enough to be able to find a .deb for the app in question (that was a patch level upgrade) and didn't have the dependency on `ia32-libs` so this question is now moot in my case, but I'll leave it open in case someone knows how to solve it where that workaround doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`ia32-libs` is obsolete and was removed from Ubuntu ages ago. If you have unofficial packages that depend on it, contact their respective developers about obtaining a more recent version.