# Upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 with live USB on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 13.04

I have dual boot Win7/Ubuntu 12.10. I have a 13.04 live USB. How can I upgrade the 12.10 install from the live USB?

I read previous questions here that answer this question - they all say that the upgrade option comes up when you hit install. In my case, the options that come up are "Install Ubuntu alongside other OSes", fresh install, and "something else". I tried the first and last of those options, and neither of them showed any option for upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your network connection is up and you reach ubuntu repos.

According to [How do I upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279620/how-do-i-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04):

> Insert the live CD or boot from the live CD to start installing it will give a option of upgrading to 13.04 **if we have a functional Internet connection only**. It will automatically detect installed applications and install the updated version of your applications also.

Without network you can't upgrade since Offline upgrade has been deprecated (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes):

> Offline upgrade options via alternate CDs are no longer offered for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server.