# "The software on this computer is up to date" while upgrading 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, upgrade

Before you guys close this question as duplicate, I did go through [How do I upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279620/how-do-i-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04) and nothing solves my problem there.

When I try to upgrade my ubuntu 12.10 installation it says

> The software on this computer is up to date.
>
> There are no upgrades available for your system. The upgrade will now
>   be canceled.

Here's a snapshot:

[image]

Question: how to fix this issue and upgrade 12.10 to 13.04?

**Update**

I tried @montazeri's command and cated release file. Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: No! it's not. Methods defined there aren't working! I have a weird error

Comment: What happened after you clicked close? Have you tried running the upgrade again?

Comment: yes I did try to run again and again. After I clicked close, process just closed. Nothing else...

Comment: How about upgrading from the command line. Try a `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Need to go to the Chat room to help.

Comment: What does "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y" get you? Maybe try that before doing Oli's "sudo do-release-upgrade"

Comment: did you choose to be able to upgrade from LTS to normal distribution in **software sources**

Comment: +1 to montazeri's question.  And, while this may not be a duplicate of the post you linked, there are dozens of questions already about this same topic, all of which swear they are not duplicates.  Are you sure you have checked those answered questions?

Comment: updated the question with montazeri's command. And I can swear I checked all.

Answer (score -1):

Question here, have you tried looking at the System Settings > Software & Updates information? Specifically on the updates tab, look at the drop-down where it states:

Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:

If it does not say 'For any new version' but instead says anything else, then this would occur.

Answer (score -1):

I would first try

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

and make sure the it prints the version you should be running.  Assuming it is, try

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

to ensure all necessary packages are up to date.  Then perform a

```
do-release-upgrade
```

from the command line.  If that doesn't work try

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

prior to installing the release upgrade.

Comment: I already mentioned I tried all this.