# Upgrade Ubuntu to 13.04 from 12.10 on dual-boot laptop

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, upgrade

Is there a possibility to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 ? I booted from the 13.04 installation CD but I couldn't do the upgrade (no upgrade option was displayed).

I have a laptop with a Windows 7 dual-boot.

Thanks ...

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu! Please see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/279620/how-do-i-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04) for various ways on upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04. For future questions, please search this website before writing your question in case your question has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Search update manager, click the Check button to check for new updates. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, press Check again after that first update is complete — then press the Upgrade button and then click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.